# Small bright constellation on the photo

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing, photography, constellations

I did a photo of the night sky and wanted to find a constellation on it. I've suggestion that it is Delphinus constellation. Could you please help me figure it out. Also, I'm curios about good way to figure out constellations on a photo.

[image]

Comment: aahhh the Pleiades are lovely. Do you see the blue tinge around them in your photo? That's the nebulosity from dust reflecting the light of the blue stars

Comment: I think when asking such questions, it would be helpful to know place, time and direction. Still some specialists can tell without knowing that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are the [Pleiades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleiades). I verified it comparing your photo with the Stellarium app.

Answer (score 27):

The object inside the red circle is indeed The Pleiades. Note that it is not a constellation, it is an open star cluster located in the constellation Taurus.

A good way to identify constellations in a photograph is to use the [Astrometry](https://nova.astrometry.net/upload) website, where you can upload a photograph of the sky and the application searches for the constellation it belongs to.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I tried Astrometry, it unfortunately didn't recognise the photo

Comment: It's also considered an asterism -- a recognizable formation smaller than a constellation.

Comment: @pacman for "fun" you might try to crop just the cluster itself and re-run it in Astrometry. I've never had any success with that site, ever, but I've always tried large areas of the sky from a handheld camera or similar, and I think it's primarily a "plate solver" meaning used for images taken through telescopes (i.e. small fields of view). Also just for "fun" [How (the heck) does Astrometry.net work?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33575/7982) which seems to suggest that other people DO have success with wide angle photos, just not me :-)